# Variable change with pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm doing a little game in C using pthread.
I have a matrix (2d table of int) who has some character represent by number (3,4,5, other number aren't thread ).
Those character must move in my matrix.
`serveurAff` is used to show the table.

`tabD`, `tabCrim` and `tabJournaliste` are global. They are all pointers.

Here my code of my `main`:

```
int statut, i,arg[2];
while (!serveurAff.fin)
    pthread_cond_wait(&serveurAff.termine, &serveurAff.mutex);
serveurAff.reqATraiter = 1;
serveurAff.fin = 0;
pthread_cond_signal(&serveurAff.requete);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&serveurAff.mutex);
//detective thread
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    arg[0] = tabD[i]->posY;
    arg[1] = tabD[i]->posX;
    printf("test1 \n ");
    statut = pthread_create(&tabD[i]->threaddete, NULL, routinePersonne, (void *) &arg);
}
//criminel thread
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    arg[0] = tabCrim[i]->posY;
    arg[1] = tabCrim[i]->posX;
    printf("test2 \n ");
    statut = pthread_create(&tabCrim[i]->threadcrim, NULL, routinePersonne, (void *) &arg);
}
//thread journaliste
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    arg[0] = tabJournaliste[i]->posY;
    arg[1] = tabJournaliste[i]->posX;
    printf("test3 \n ");
    statut = pthread_create(&tabJournaliste[i]->threadjour, NULL, routinePersonne, (void *) &arg);
}
pthread_join(threadAff, NULL);
```

When I write a `printf` before starting my pthread, for "some iteration" position are ok

```
   test1 
 test1 
 test1 
 test2 
 test2 
 test2 
 test2 
 test2 
 test3 
 test3 
 test3 
 coord1 => 9, coord0, 1 
xancien => 9 yancien => 1 
coord1 => 20, coord0, 7 
xancien => 20 yancien => 7 
azazaz









Etape 0
01   5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
02   0 4 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
03   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
04   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
05   0 0 3 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 
coord1 => 2, coord0, 4 
xancien => 2 yancien => 4 
coord1 => 0, coord0, 0 
coord1 => 20, coord0, 7 
xancien => 20 yancien => 7 
coord1 => 23, coord0, 4 
xancien => 23 yancien => 4 
xancien => 0 yancien => 0 
coord1 => 0, coord0, 0 
xancien => 0 yancien => 0 
coord1 => 20, coord0, 7 
xancien => 20 yancien => 7 
06   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 
07   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
08   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 3 0 0 0 3 0 0 
09   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
coord1 => 23, coord0, 4 
xancien => 23 yancien => 4 
coord1 => 0, coord0, 0 
xancien => 0 yancien => 0 
coord1 => 0, coord0, 0 
xancien => 0 yancien => 0 
coord1 => 0, coord0, 0 
xancien => 0 yancien => 0
```

As you can see after some iteration all values are 0 ...
And if I dont write `printf("test1")` before starting my threads, values are equal to 0 at all times.

Here a part of `routinePersonne`:

```
void *routinePersonne(void *arg) {
while (1){
int* coord = (int*)arg;     
        int xancien = coord[1]; 
        int yancien = coord[0];
        printf("coord1 => %d, coord0, %d \n",xancien,yancien);
        printf("xancien => %d yancien => %d \n",xancien,yancien);

        int i =0;
        crimines* c;
        detective* d;
        journaliste* j;
        //on récupére le type de la personne
        int element = g->carte[yancien][xancien];
        switch(element){
            case CRIMINEL:
                c = malloc(sizeof(criminels));
                while(tabCrim[i]->posX != xancien && tabCrim[i]->posY != yancien){
                    i++;
                }
                c = tabCrim[i];
            break;
            case DETECTIVE:
                d = malloc(sizeof(detective));
                while(tabD[i]->posX != xancien && tabD[i]->posY != yancien){
                    i++;
                }
                d = tabD[i];
            break;
            case JOURNALISTE:
                j = malloc(sizeof(journaliste));
                while(tabJournaliste[i]->posX != xancien && tabJournaliste[i]->posY != yancien){
                    i++;
                }
                j = tabJournaliste[i];
        }
...
}
```

So I think its a problem of synchronization, but I dont know where ...

ps: sorry for my English :)

Comment: Should we account for the memory leaks in every one of your switch cases when formulating our answer?

Comment: hum I'm listening you. Should I malloc before my while ?

Comment: Take one case: CRIMINEL: `c` is assigned a pointer to a dynamic allocation, then a while-loop commences that neither uses, nor touches the allocated memory, and finally, c is assigned what looks like a pointer (for all we know) from `tabCrim[i]`. So.... what happened to the dynamic memory that was first allocated? Answer: It is still allocated, but the only pointer to it was just overwritten by something else. You just leaked memory. This same problem is in each case. Now, post complete, concise, **compilable** code that *demonstrates* any issue your having. See [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

You use the same `arg` array for all threads. So your threads will all share a single set of coordinates. While I still can't point exactly at the line of code where these coordinates become zero, it might well be that some re-initialization from some `posY` and `posX` account for that. Hard to tell without the code for that.

On the other hand, your `malloc` calls appear prety pointless, since you don't do anything with that memory, and even overwrite the pointer eventually, thus creating a memory leak. Perhaps you are missing the fact that C does not have an assignment operator for arrays. You can write `a = b` if `a` is of type `int*` and `b` is of type `int*` or `int[]`, but this will *not* copy all elements, but instead simply store the address of the array `b` in the variable `a`. Use `memcpy` to create copies.

Comment: Ok, so we worked on this with my friends this afternoon. We corrected our mistake that you indicate. The problem was what you said MvG. We used same table for every thread.
However we had a 2nd error, it wasn't '&&' for condition but '||'.
Next time, I will copy all my code.
Thank's both of you !